# When did Archer maroon a ship full of innocent people?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, episode-identification

In [Home (4x03)](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Home_(episode)), on the mountain with his old girlfriend, Archer says he marooned a ship full of people and tortured someone.

> **ERIKA:** *You did what any captain would have done.*
>
> **ARCHER:** *Does that include torture? Or marooning a ship full of innocent people? Because I don't remember reading those chapters in
>   the handbook*

I assume the person he tortured is the one that he put in an air lock but when did he maroon a "***ship full of innocent people***"?

Comment: The episode where he takes the warp drive by force when they refuse to trade it.

Comment: Aww, I thought this was a question about [Archer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archer_(TV_series)), it sounds like the kinda thing he'd do

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***"Marooning a ship full of innocent people?***" is a reference to [Damage](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Damage_(episode)) (Episode 3x19)

> With a boarding party, Archer, and Trip transport onto the vessel, and
>   manage to steal their warp coil while leaving behind three containers
>   of trellium-D as well as other supplies in 'compensation'. When the
>   Captain asks why Archer is doing this, Archer simply states that he
>   has no choice before leaving, knowing that by taking their warp coil
>   the alien crew has been left stranded three years from their home.

"***Does that include torture?***" is a reference to [Anomaly](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Anomaly_(episode)) (Episode 3x02)

> Archer enters the brig and, holding a phase pistol to Orgoth's neck,
>   escorts him to the airlock, startling some of the crewmembers on the
>   way. Shoving him into the airlock, Orgoth refuses to respond, still
>   thinking Archer is too civilized. Archer starts to decompress the
>   airlock, saying that if he doesn't talk, he has less than forty
>   seconds to live...Realizing that Archer wasn't bluffing,
>   Orgoth says he'll give Archer the information he needs.

Comment: I never understood how it could possible take only three years for that crew to get home without warp drive.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - A good question.

Comment: With an annoying spelling mistake in it that I now can't correct >.<

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - "Nothing can possiblie go wrong."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - 3 years subjective, perhaps?  AFAIK, outside of warp, relativity still applies in Trek and impulse drive is capable of accelerating ships to relativistic velocities.

Comment: @Compro01: Heh, true. Still, they've never indicated that this actually happens within the ST universe as far as I know.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - It's mentioned in the ST TNG Technical Manual.

Comment: @Richard: And pp. 44-45 state that guidance and navigation research is conducted by a cetacean crew of twelve Bottlenose Dolphins (Tursiops truncatus) and Pacific Bottlenose Dolphins (Tursiops truncatus gilli), overseen by two Takaya's Whales (Orcinus orca takayai).

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - ironically, that's actually referenced in one of the films and is considered canon

Comment: The giant rubber duck is, however just an easter egg.

Comment: @Richard: Er, which film is that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - My apologies, not a film, it was a reference from TNG : Yesterday's Enterprise; http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Joshua_Kim

Comment: @Richard: That says nothing whatsoever about what Cetacean Operations does, whether there are cetaceans there, and how many dolphins _if any_ crew it!

Comment: That's true, but the TNG manual is considered 'canon unless contradicted'.

Comment: @valorum So.. it's true when it's true, and false when it's not true. Is it just a bunch of facts make up arbitrarily (much like the actual canon) and whatever sticks, sticks?! If that's the case I'm not sure I understand the point of the manual.

Comment: @apraetor - That;s how canon works in an awfully large number of fictional universes. The writers of the, vastly more popular, shows and movies usually reserve the ultimate right to break canon from a tie-in book. After all, it's their property and they can do what they like with it